# Dealing with git, generated files and bower

Tags: git, bower

I know that it is considered a bad practice to commit generated files to a git repository. But how to deal with bower?

Currently my library is built into a `dist/` directory which gets ignored by a `.gitignore` file. I don't want generated files pushed to the repository. The problem is that the library is also distributed as a bower component.

How can I reference the generated assets into my bower component when a new version got released? Should I create another repository to store those files? Should I commit those files to the git tagged version?

Comment: Related: ignore `bower_components` or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327758/bower-shouldnt-we-gitignore-something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already mentioned your choices. There aren't really a best way. Choose what you prefer. Either create a new repo or commit the `/dist` folder. Both have upsides and downsides. Creating a repo makes it more cumbersome to update and committing makes the repo more bloated.

The Bower team is working on a way to publish releases to a server, which will resolve this issue.

Comment: any movement on this? We're starting to use bower as a way of install javascript libs and the bloat is astronomical.

Comment: @Sindre can you link to a source for the release server initiative?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to challenge the idea that committing built files is a bad practice, and I do that [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259555/is-committing-built-files-a-bad-practice-also-in-web-develoment).

About handling built files with git, check also [this excellent post](http://blog.andrewray.me/dealing-with-compiled-files-in-git/).