# Is "bower install" a good idea for release builds?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, build, gulp, bower

I have experienced problems with my jenkins server since yesterday: `bower install` fails to download dependencies from Github repositories. As far as we know this may depends on connection issues with the server (jenkins).

How can I avoid this kind of risks? 
Should I commit dependencies along with my project and write a specific task (Gulpjs/Gruntjs) that works with it in locale?

Comment: Discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327758/should-bower-components-be-gitignored
In my opinion you should ignore dependencies.